# Get data from relationship with AsyncCrudAppService

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I am using asp.net boilerplate and I want to return from an api call a DTO having a property which  has to be get from the relation of the entity.

The service is simple inhereting from AsyncCrudAppService:

```
public class ItemAppService : AsyncCrudAppService<Core.Item, ItemDto>, IItemAppService
{
    ...
}
```

I need to get the description from category (that is a relationship, see below) when requesting any of the Get or GetAll methods, that returns the ItemDTO.

```
public class ItemDto : EntityDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryDescription { get; set; }
}
```

For clarification, I have the following two entities with a relationship.

```
public class Item : Entity {

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

}
```

```
public class Category : Entity {

    public string Description { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }   

}
```

Resulting in the following relationship in the EntityFrameworkCore mapping:

```
...
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Item> builder)
{
    builder.HasOne<Category>(e => e.Category).WithMany(c => c.Items).HasForeignKey(c => c.CategoryId);
}
```

The automapper profile configuration:

```
public class ItemProfile : Profile
{
     public ItemProfile()
     {
         CreateMap<ItemDto, Core.Item>();             

         CreateMap<Core.Item, ItemDto>()
                .ForMember(p => p.CategoryDescription, options => options.MapFrom(x => x.Category.Description));
    }
}
```

For now CategoryDesciption in ItemDto is returning null, obviously because it is not mapped right. Can I do something with automapper to get the description or how it can be done.

Comment: Show how you configured the mapping from `Item` to `ItemDto`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your mapping is correct but the problem is that you are not getting the related entities, as the `AsyncCrudAppService` will not include any relation by default. (check the `GetAllAsync` method implementation [here](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/059db7626b3642114b7a2ba7d15b6a14304640dd/src/Abp/Application/Services/AsyncCrudAppService.cs#L112)

you need to include it yourself by overwriting the `CreateFilteredQuery` method (check the implementation [here](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/059db7626b3642114b7a2ba7d15b6a14304640dd/src/Abp/Application/Services/CrudAppServiceBase.cs#L98))

```
return Repository.GetAll().Include(x=>x.Category);
```

Comment: I think this is the right answer, I was hoping to get the related entities by default. But overriding the CreateFilteredQuery is a simple solution.

Comment: You can implement your own version that include all related entities by inhereting from the `AsyncCrudAppService` and overriding the method and using reflection to include the related entities